# Multi find search in ruby with date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a multi find search, where I need to filter records by date / category / title. Searching by a category and/or title works, however, when date is typed it doesn't change anything (the results is the same like there was no date typed). I have no idea what else I could do to fix it, I am just a beginner in Ruby. Any idea?

Model:

```
 def self.multi_find(cat_id, search,  date_search)
    search_condition = "%" + search + "%"
    #date_condition =  date_search
# test if cat_id is not blank
    if not cat_id.blank? 
        # assign the value of cat_id to a ‘scope’ named :cat 
        scope :cat, -> { where('category_id = ?', cat_id) }
        # using the ‘scope’ cat find where a search string is like a title or an author’s name
        self.cat.where("title LIKE ? or event_date = ?", search_condition, date_search.to_date)
    else
  # find where a search string is like a title or an author’s name
        self.where("title LIKE ? or event_date = ?", search_condition, date_search.to_date) 
    end
end
```

Controller:

```
  def multi_find
# call an Event class method, using two parameters; a category unique identifier and a search string (author or title)
events = Event.multi_find(params[:cat_id], params[:search_string], params[:event_date_search])
# use Kaminari pagination ...
@events = Kaminari.paginate_array(events.order :title).page(params[:page]).per(6)
# if no products have been found
if @events.empty?
  # display a notice
  flash.now[:alert] = "No events found - so displaying all events"
  # then display all products
  @events = Event.order(:title).page(params[:page]).per(6)
end 
# use the index view
render :action => "index" 
end
```

The console outputs the SQL Query

```
  Event Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (category_id = '1') AND (title LIKE '%%' or event_date = '2018-02-14') ORDER BY "events"."title" ASC
```

View file:

```
<%= form_tag my_path, :method=>'post', :multipart => true do %>
```

```
<%= select_tag ('cat_id'), 
        options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, :id, :cat_name, 0 ),
        :prompt => "Select a Category" %>

<div class="datepicker"> 
  <% @event_date_format %> 
  <%= text_field_tag :event_date_search  %>

</div>

<!-- Key word:-->
    <%= text_field_tag :search_string %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything because you have an _or_ in your sql.

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I missed that. Thank you very much, I appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have an `or` in your sql statement. However you should also clean up your code a bit.

```
def self.multi_find(cat_id, search,  date_search)
  result = self.all

  result = result.where(category_id: cat_id) if cat.id.present?
  result = result.where('title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%") if search.present?
  result = result.where(event_date: date_search) if date_search.present?

  result
end
```